# Is there a rule to the name a link bean table gets given in Redbean?

Tags: php, orm, redbean

I have a few link bean tables that were built by Redbean - each was created as a result of the following type of code;

```
//generates tag_video table
$tags = R::findAll('tag');
$video = R::dispense('video');
$video->sharedTag = $tags;
R::store($video);

//generates image_tag table
$image = R::dispense('image');
$image->sharedTag = $tags;
R::store($image);

//generates document_tag table
$document = R::dispense('document');
$document->sharedTag = $tags;
R::store($document);
```

Most of my link bean tables are named **image_tag**, **document_tag**. But I also have **tag_video**, which is a problem. I would prefer *video_tag*.

I'd like to be able to predict the link bean table names because I want to use them in JOIN's for times when I query the database directly, rather than using the ORM.

Is there a rule? Is it alphabetic perhaps? Can I insist on the 'parent' object type coming first in the table name?

Comment: I feel certain that @gabor-de-mooij can answer this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have since discovered that the link tables are always named alphabetically.

Here is the response from the developer.

> The tables are always named alphabetically. Unfortunately given the
>   fact that RB strives to be zero-conf, it's not recommended to enforce
>   a naming convention. RedBeanPHP allows you to change most of the
>   schema policy rules but I recommend not to do this because it will
>   break things and defeat the purpose of RB althoghether.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to constantly try to remember what the hell the bean named the table, `R::xdispense`

Because then you can use underscores and structure your data as you feel; while still using the basic CRUD functionality just fine.